# Display a custom horizontal scrollbar on both events 'mousemove' and 'scroll' and then hide the scrollbar when neither event is fired for ~1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have a custom scrollbar that I only want visible when the mouse is moved on the page (entire body, not just within the #scrolling-wrapper) or the div #scrolling-wrapper is scrolled. When the mouse has been still for ~1 second (or however long is the default for typical scrollbars) and there has been no scrolling, the scrollbar should fade out. It should work like a default auto hiding scrollbar, but with my custom styling. The only difference is that it should also appear when the mouse is moved rather than only when the div is scrolled as users with a mouse will not be able to scroll within the horizontal div with their mouse wheel... thus needing the scrollbar to appear when the mouse is moved.

Here is a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jde7s1kr/) that features @nidhin-joseph's solution, which is close but it does not work correctly 100% of the time like I need it to. Sometimes the scrollbar will not appear on mouse move or scroll and sometimes it does not disappear. The code is also forcing the videos to slightly jump up and down at times (a problem that was not occurring prior to adding the JS events to show / hide the scrollbar). I'm assuming this has to do with the scrollbar appearing and forcing the videos upwards slightly. This cannot happen either.

So to clarify: when a mouse is moved or the div is scrolled I need the scrollbar visible and whenever either of those two actions do not occur for ~1 second, the scrollbar can fade out.

Code:

```
<div id="horizontalcontainer">
  <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="videocard1">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocardlast">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 2%;
    display: var(--scroll-display);
}

:root {
    --scroll-display: none;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#horizontalcontainer {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.videocard1 {
    padding-left: 27%;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46.5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.videocard {
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 46.5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.videocardlast {
    padding-right: 27%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 46.5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by all browsers? I see you’re using CSS Custom Properties here, those are not supported in IE11

Comment: I overlooked that, my apologies. The answer I've accepted is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the details you submitted,
This solution offer you the customization you want for your famous custom scrollbar.
This solution offer browser compatibility.
This solution offer css only or Css + jS callback

Found issues in your code
You want it compatible with 100% browser but use specific Webkit Css?
By default scroll-bars takes +/- 20px of the viewport it usualy need to be taken into accounts? That's why content jump around when you show/hide default overflow scrollbars. It's not a bug it's a feature. Only on mobile the standard scroll is over the content.

So to fullfill your requirements. Here's what you need to do, use a framework that take into account the multiple caveats of the different browser, if not you'll be tweaking Javascript and Css forever each time to test it in a new browser.
In this case here ill Be Using SimpleBar to allow you customization And use Jquery to trigger SimpleBar Into Action And set the timeout to "2000" miliseconds This will work in modern browser '100% of the time'.

Simplebar
https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar

Working JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ft9h210g/12/

HTML

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>

    <div id="horizontalcontainer">
      <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
        <div class="videocard1">
          <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </div>
        <div class="videocard">
          <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </div>
        <div class="videocard">
          <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </div>
        <div class="videocardlast">
          <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
    const simplebar = new SimpleBar(document.querySelector('#scrolling-wrapper'), {
    autoHide: true,
  timeout: 2000
});
```

css

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
}

#scrollable {
  height: 200px;
}

.simplebar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1%;
  display: var(--scroll-display);
}

:root {
  --scroll-display: none;
}



#horizontalcontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 /*
 height: 100%;
*/
height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100vw;
/* 
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
*/
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.videocard1 {
  padding-left: 27%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
/*   top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); */
}

.videocard {
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
 /* top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); */
}

.videocardlast {
  padding-right: 27%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
/*  top:0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); */
}
```

I modified the original css To show where the Horizontal scroll Can end up showing, ex:

```
#horizontalcontainer {
 /*
 height: 100%; //show at the bottom
*/
height: 400px; //show after 400px
}
```

but you can change it to the taste of your project. You can use Jquery and Simplebar from CDN or move the CSS + JS files it to your project, to customize The scroll bar you need to Download simplebar.css and / or overwrite the css properties of simplebar.css with your own customizations.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css-variable` to set value for the `::-webkit-scrollbar` and based on mouse movement, change the variable value and track it using `setInterval` to hide the scrollbar after 2 seconds.

**NOTE**: For some strange reason, this does not work when clicking run snippet, user the full view and it will work. Guess with iframe or something.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('scrolling-wrapper');
var myTimer = setInterval(onTimer, 2000);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  showScroll();
  resetTimer();
});

function onTimer() {
  hideScroll();
}

function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(onTimer, 2000);
}

function showScroll() {
  div.style.setProperty('--scroll-display', 'block');
}


function hideScroll() {
  div.style.setProperty('--scroll-display', 'none');
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1%;
  display: var(--scroll-display);
}

:root {
  --scroll-display: none;
}

#scrolling-wrapper:hover> ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#horizontalcontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: calc(100% - 145px);
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.videocard1 {
  padding-left: 27%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.videocard {
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.videocardlast {
  padding-right: 27%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46.5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontalcontainer">
  <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="videocard1">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocardlast">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately it does still seem to be pretty wonky even at full page in terms of when the scrollbar appears and when it vanishes. For example, sometimes moving the mouse after scrolling through the videos is not making the scrollbar visible again. Additionally, at times, when the mouse does not move for more than 2 seconds, the scrollbar is still visible. I'm also noticing the videos very slightly jump up and then back down at times which was not happening prior. Could using the body rather than the #scrolling-wrapper perhaps solve some of these issues?

Comment: Additionally, I've realized that I need the scrollbar to also be visible when a mouse wheel is turned or a trackpad / magic mouse is used. Is this possible with the css-variable as well? When a mouse is moved or the div is scrolled I need the scrollbar visible and whenever either of those two actions do not occur for two seconds, the scrollbar can vanish.

Comment: yes, you need to conditionally call the hide and show method as per your requirement. For all we know now is how to hide and show it. You need to define, as per your use case when to call these.

Comment: I've created this (https://jsfiddle.net/abounhjf/) fiddle with that hide / show script, but have yet to get it to work correctly. I have also added the 'scroll' event, but it does not seem to be working correctly either. Do you see where it is going wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: You should use `mwheel` instead of `scroll` event.